# Python WebSocket Client Stack Overflow Reconnecting

Tags: python, class, websocket, client, stack-overflow

I created a class for a WebSocket client that reopen when disconnecting unintentionely. After several disconnection, I have a Python stack overflow.

- Why do I have this issue ? I think it comes from the infinite loop trying to reconnect, but this is the behaviour intended
- Is there a way to avoid this issue ? if yes, how ? If no, why ?

Any comments will be much appreciated. I hope this will help others

Here is my class:

```
import websocket
import json

class MyWebSocketClient(object):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.connected = False
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            url=self.URL,
            on_open=self.on_open,
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_close=self.on_close,
            on_error=self.on_error,
        )
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.ws.keep_running = False

    def send(self, data: dict):
        data = json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"), indent=None)
        self.ws.send(data)

    def on_open(self):
        logger.info('Connexion opened')
        self.connected = True

    def on_message(self, data):
        logger.info(f'Data received: {data}')

    def on_close(self):
        logger.info(f'Connection closed')
        self.connected = False
        if self.running:
           self.start()

    def on_error(self, err):
        logger.error(f'Error: {err}')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be because the old thread is not really closed and then related memory is not released...

An useful link on a Github thread may be this this one:

[LINK TO DISCUSSION ON GITHUB](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/580)